# Meaning of そんだけ in this context

Tags: spoken-language, contractions

丸尾 is assertively ensuring that his teacher remembers his name. The teacher replies:

> そんだけ売りこめば忘れたくても忘れないよ。
>   If you sell yourself (arrogantly?) I won't forget even if I wanted to.

Im guessing that そんだけ derives from そんだい. If so what is the 
grammar? How would it differ from そんだいに?

**Edit:** just realised that this guess is probably nonsense because there would be no reason to remove the い. Nonetheless, I still don't understand what そんだけ means in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それだけ(soredake)：So much
↓
Omission of the pronunciation
↓
そんだけ(sondake)

Comment: Thanks. It seems counter-intuitive to me that a word involving だけ (only) can have a translation involving 'much'.

Comment: だけ in the word それだけ means "as much as" rather than "only".